# How to change an image every 15 seconds in HTML

Tags: html

I have an image in my HTML page, and I would like it to change to a different image every 15 seconds.

```
<img src="img/img 1.jpg" alt="image">
```

In my local folder `img`, I have two images which are `img 1.jpg` and `img 2.jpg`. How do I change the `img 1.jpg` to `img 2.jpg` after 15 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly include jQuery library in your page.
2. Then use this script:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       setInterval(function(){
           _path = $('img').attr('src');
           _img_id = _path.replace('img/img', '');
           _img_id = _img_id.replace('.jpg', '');

           _img_id++;

           if (_img_id == 3) {
               _img_id = 1;
           };

           $('img').attr('src', 'img/img' + _img_id + '.jpg');
       }, 15000);
   });
   ```

Comment: Firstly change your image names from "img 1.jpg" to "img1.jpg" (delete the empty spaces). Secondly open your console (F12) and see for an error.

Comment: this code is fine if op is already using jquery. and why to use jQuery when you can do the same using Pure JavaScript @ViktorMaksimov ?

Comment: If you are thinking like this then why everybody at all to use jQuery instead of pure Javascript while everything can be coded in Javascript. jQuery is a brilliant library which will help a lot to the people which use it. He can include now the jQuery and later to use it again in different situations.

Answer (score 3):

Try it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var img = 0;

    var slides = new Array();

    while (img < 5) {

        img++;

        // put your image src in sequence

        var src = 'assets/images/earth/Sequence' + img + '.jpg';

        slides.push(src);

    }

    var index = 0,timer = 0;

    showNextSlide();

    timer = setInterval(showNextSlide, 15000);

    function showNextSlide() {

        if (index >= slides.length) {

            index = 0;

        }

        document.getElementById('earth').src = slides[index++];
    }

});
```

Comment: Might want to format your code and mention this requires jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Try this (pure JS)

```js
var myArray = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5', 'img6']

var count = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  //use this below line if you want random images
  //var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

  if (count >= myArray.length) count = 0; // if it is last image then show the first image.
  // use this below line if you want images in order.
  var rand = myArray[count];
  document.getElementById('img').src = rand;
  document.getElementById('img').alt = rand; // use 'alt' to display the image name if image is not found
  count++;
}, 1000); // 1000 = 1 second
```

```html
<img src="img/img 1.jpg" alt="image" id='img' />
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you're going to need some Javascript to change the image. Here is a link to a popular website for help with Javascript, HTML, CSS, and a whole lot more. What you'll want to be looking at specifically though, is the setInterval() function on this page: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

If you don't know Javascript at all, it is also not a bad place to start learning! If that's all you need it for though, you'll need very little Javascript at all.